# Is there a way to theme with emotion without "styled"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion

With `emotion` (https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion) I know I can theme with `css` and `styled` together with something like:

```
const carouselCss = ({ theme }) => css`
 .. css properties etc
`;

const CarouselDiv = styled('div')`
  ${carouselCss};
`;
```

Then in JSX:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={{ stuff: 'blah' }}>
  <CarouselDiv>
        ..
  </CarouselDiv>
</ThemeProvider>
```

But is there any elegant way to theme with only `css` - prefer not to use componentized `styles` because I want to keep to semantic html elements in JSX (also have a massive code base and its easier to migrate from sass to emotion without having to use `styled`)

I know I can do something like:

```
const carouselCss = (theme) => css`
 .. css properties etc
`;
```

then jsx:

```
<div className={carouselCss(this.props.theme)}>
..
</div>
```

But it means passing a theme prop all the time from the component - which is a little cumbersome

Is there a better way to do this ? Somehow wrap `css` with something so it has theme vars injected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThemeProvider` will get you that. Here is an example with both `styled` and `css` options shown :

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from '@emotion/core'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'emotion-theming'

const theme = {
  colors: {
    primary: 'hotpink'
  }
}

const SomeText = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.primary};
`

render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <SomeText>some text</SomeText>
    <div css={theme => ({ color: theme.colors.primary })}>
      some other text
    </div>
  </ThemeProvider>
)
```

Comment: My question is about doing theming without `@emotion/styled`

Comment: @Marty I provided you with 2 options in the example, one is using styled and one is using css prop directly on the div: `<div css={theme => css\`color: ${theme.colors.primary}\`}>I am styled!</div>`

Comment: Ah yep correct - this was supported since emotion 10 (when i posted the article only emotion 9 was around)

Comment: @Marty @Saša Šijak, can we inject theme on the following syntax : 
import { css } from "@emotion/css";

export const ToolTipStyle = theme=> css`
color : blue
`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [theme HoC](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/tree/master/packages/emotion-theming#withthemecomponent-reactcomponent-function). But if your concern is prop passing to slider, this HoC is basically doing the same, i.e. injects `theme` into `this.props.theme`.
Personally, i would use [ThemeProvider API](https://emotion.sh/docs/emotion-theming#themeprovider-reactcomponent) if possible, maybe with function-style theme, as pointed out in the docs:

```
// function-style theme; note that if multiple <ThemeProvider> are used,
// the parent theme will be passed as a function argument

const adjustedTheme = ancestorTheme => ({ ...ancestorTheme, color: 'blue' });
```

Comment: `withTheme` requires you to pass a react component, what i need is to make a `css` literal theme aware. The `adjustedTheme` method uses `styled` which is what im trying to avoid if possible

Comment: Maybe you can try something along these lines: https://codesandbox.io/s/n93lxvq7m0 (forked from emotion live demo). Theme object are available inside `getBorderProps`